# Mailchimp Button with _Blank target not opening in new window :(

Tags: html, css, forms, mailchimp

I've styled my Mailchimp subscribe form, but for some reason the button isn't popping the "success" or "failure" in a new window. Instead, it's inserting it below the form, which obviously screws up my page layout.

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
                        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
                <div id="optin">
                <form action="//scottdaviesdesign.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6a0182b1b060f7307996ee031&amp;id=26cb77a478" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=";" onblur="if(this.value==")this.value=this.defaultValue;" class="required email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_6a0182b1b060f7307996ee031_26cb77a478" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
                </form>
                </div>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
                <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had missed the

```
                <div id="mc_embed_signup">
```

tag.

Problem solved.  Sorry.